# Which monad to use in Haskell for aggregating exceptions that may happen while executing a sequence of statements?

Tags: haskell, exception, error-handling, io, monads

I am looking for the most common way to do something like:

```
x :: IO ((),[SomeException])
x = do
  void y
  void z
```

aggregating exceptions that may be thrown by `y` and `z` and returning them as part of the type of `x`.

Is there a well-known monad / tutorial for this?

Comment: You can't have multiple errors with just a Monad (i.e. using only bind and return) - see Duncan Coutts "Arrows for Errors: extending the Error Monad". http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/duncan.coutts/papers/arrows_for_errors.pdf. You can program Applicatively with multiple errors (see Conor McBride an Ross Paterson's Applicative paper) but then you don't have monadic bind so you can't use a successful result in subsequent steps.

Comment: If y throws an exception, what would the value if a be?

Comment: @augustss Oh you are right! Actually I was voiding the results in my actual code as I was not interested in their results.

Comment: Well, in Haskell you can always use `undefined` for "voiding the result".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the important question here is `augustss` - "If y throws an exception, what would the value of `a` be?"

If you have default values for `a`, and `b`, you can use `try` to catch your exceptions and aggregate them using `WriterT`:

```
x :: IO (C, [SomeException])
x = runWriterT $ do 
  a <- rescue defaultA y 
  b <- rescue defaultB z 
  return $ f a b

rescue :: a -> IO a -> WriterT [SomeException] IO a
rescue a m = do
  res <- lift $ try m
  case res of
    Left e -> do
      tell [e]
      return a
    Right a' -> return a'

data A
data B
data C

y :: IO A
y = undefined

defaultA :: A
defaultA = undefined

z :: IO B
z = undefined

defaultB :: B
defaultB = undefined

f :: A -> B -> C
f = undefined
```

Without defaults though, you can't rescue exceptions and continue computation.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) In my actual usage, almost all IO results in `x` are ignored so I guess I can do with a very short list of defaults.

Answer (score 4):

If `y` throws an exception, then you will never reach `z`. Likewise, if `z` throws an exception, that means that `y` has not thrown an exception. So the typical way to track exceptions is just tracking one -- the one that was thrown -- with `ErrorT`.

```
x :: ErrorT SomeException IO Foo
x = do
  a <- y
  b <- z
  return $ f a b

useX :: IO Quux
useX = do
  errOrVal <- runErrorT x
  case errOrVal of
    Left err -> logError err >> quux1
    Right v  -> quux2 v
```

---

Here are the type assumptions I used:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}

import Control.Monad.Error

data Foo; data Bar; data Baz; data Quux; data SomeException

instance Error SomeException

y :: ErrorT SomeException IO Bar;   y = undefined
z :: ErrorT SomeException IO Baz;   z = undefined
f :: Bar -> Baz -> Foo;             f = undefined
quux1 :: IO Quux;                   quux1 = undefined
quux2 :: Foo -> IO Quux;            quux2 = undefined
logError :: SomeException -> IO (); logError = undefined
```

Comment: Wow I really like the degree of precision you use in your answer with such explicit assumptions :)

Answer (score 4):

An important thing about exceptions is that if an `IO a` action throws an exception, you don't get any resulting `a` value. Since the bind operator `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` of monads allow later actions to depend on the results of earlier ones, this means that we can't run the following actions once one has failed.

If you have default values, you can use [rampion's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554695/98117). However, from your example it seems like you only care about the sequencing of independent actions through the `(>>)` operator. You could make a monoid out of this, but I think the simplest approach is just to have a function that runs a list of `IO ()` actions and gathers any exceptions in a list:

```
import Control.Exception (SomeException, try)
import Data.Either (lefts)

exceptions :: [IO ()] -> IO [SomeException]
exceptions = fmap lefts . mapM try
```

You'll have to use a list of actions instead of `do` notation, though:

```
> :{
| exceptions [ putStrLn "foo"
|            , throwIO DivideByZero
|            , putStrLn "bar"
|            , throwIO (IndexOutOfBounds "xyzzy")
|            ]
| :}
foo
bar
[divide by zero,array index out of range: xyzzy]
```